# JTree : Update tree after deleting nodes

Tags: java, swing, jtree, swingx, jxtreetable

I am using my own custom model for JXTree which extends from `AbstractTreeTableModel`. So  the option of `reload / removeNodeFromParent` is not there.

I have tried using `TreeModelListener` and `treeModelListener.treeNodesRemoved(event)` call with every input option possible. Never is my tree's GUI getting updated. Unless i call `tree.updateUI()` the changed structure is not getting reflected.(But that call is updating the entire tree and i just want the deleted node to be refreshed). I am using my custom tree editor and tree renderer. I have not written any custom tree listener.

So the question i ask is : **Does `listener.treeNodesRemoved()` implicitly call some code that would have the same result as `tree.updateUI()`. Or do i need to write some code myself to refresh that particular parent node from which the child was deleted**. Is the listener call not working because i am using custom tree editor and renderer.

EDIT :

I am posting an SSCCE. In this case i am not using any tree editor or rendrer but the issue can be seen using this code also.

```
    public class TestListener  extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {        
                new TestListener();
            }
        });
    }

    public TestListener(){
        Departement dept1 = new Departement("1ST DEPARTMENT");
        Departement dept2 = new Departement("2ND DEPARTMENT");
        Employee emp1 = new Employee("1ST Employee");
        Employee emp2 =  new Employee("2ND Employee");
        Employee emp3 = new Employee("3rd Employee");
        final Employee emp4 =  new Employee("4th Employee");
        ArrayList<Employee> empList1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList1.add(emp1);
        empList1.add(emp2);
        final ArrayList<Employee> empList2 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList2.add(emp3);
        empList2.add(emp4);
        dept1.setEmpList(empList1);
        dept2.setEmpList(empList2);
        ArrayList<Departement> deptList = new ArrayList<Departement>();
        deptList.add(dept1);
        deptList.add(dept2);
        TestModel model = new TestModel(deptList);
            final JXTree rootTree = new JXTree(model);
        rootTree.setShowsRootHandles(true); // to show collapse and expand icons
        rootTree.setEditable(true);
        rootTree.setRootVisible(false); //not to show the top root
        rootTree.setVisible(true);
        JButton button = new JButton("Delete Node");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    JXTree rootNew = rootTree;
                    empList2.remove(emp4);
                    TestModel model = (TestModel) rootNew.getModel();
                    TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, 
                            new Object[] {rootNew.getPathForRow(3)}, // harcoding because i know i am deleting from dept2
                            new int[]{1}, //hardcoding as i am removing emp4
                            new Object[] {emp4});
                    TreeModelListener[] listeners = model.getTreeModelListeners();
                    for (TreeModelListener listener : listeners) {

                        listener.treeNodesRemoved(event);
                    }

                }
            });   

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(rootTree));
        this.getContentPane().add(button);
        this.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 400));
        this.setLocation(280, 50);
        this.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();


    }
}
```

TestModel Class

```
public class TestModel extends AbstractTreeTableModel {

    private final static String[] COLUMN_NAMES = { "LABEL" };
    public TestModel(ArrayList<Departement> depList) {
        super(depList);
        this.depList = depList;
    }

    private ArrayList<Departement> depList;
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.jdesktop.swingx.treetable.TreeTableModel#getColumnCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {

        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.jdesktop.swingx.treetable.TreeTableModel#getValueAt(java.lang.Object, int)
     */
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(Object arg0, int arg1) {
        if (arg0 instanceof Employee) {
            Employee emp = (Employee) arg0;

            JLabel newLabel =  new JLabel();
            newLabel.setText(emp.getName());
            return (JLabel)newLabel;

        } else if (arg0 instanceof Departement) {
            Departement dept = (Departement) arg0;

            JLabel newLabel =  new JLabel();
            newLabel.setText(dept.getName());
            return (JLabel)newLabel;

        }

        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.swing.tree.TreeModel#getChild(java.lang.Object, int)
     */
    @Override
    public Object getChild(Object arg0, int arg1) {
        if (arg0 instanceof Departement) {
            Departement dept = (Departement) arg0;
            return dept.getEmpList().get(arg1);
        }

        return depList.get(arg1);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.swing.tree.TreeModel#getChildCount(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public int getChildCount(Object arg0) {
        if (arg0 instanceof Departement) {
            Departement dept = (Departement) arg0;
            return dept.getEmpList().size();
        }

        if (arg0 instanceof Employee) {
            return 0;
        }

        return this.depList.size();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.swing.tree.TreeModel#getIndexOfChild(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        Departement dept = (Departement) arg0;
        Employee emp = (Employee) arg1;
        return dept.getEmpList().indexOf(emp);
    }

}
```

The Department and Employee class is fairly simple with a constructor and some getter/setters .

So when i click on the delete node button no action is happening on the tree. The UI is not getting updated at all. I am using swingx 1.6.4 version.

Department

```
public class Departement {

    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private ArrayList<Employee> empList;
    public ArrayList<Employee> getEmpList() {
        return empList;
    }
    public void setEmpList(ArrayList<Employee> empList) {
        this.empList = empList;
    }
    public Departement(String name){

        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Employee

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Employee(String name){
        this.name =name;
    }
}
```

Comment: a) don't use updateUI in application code b) AbstractTreeTableModel does have support for rather simple notification, see its TreeModelSupport c) look at DefaultTreeTableModel as a guide for implementing a removeNode with proper notification d) if it still doesn't work, show your custom model (that's where your error is), best with a SSCCE so that we can reproduce/fix it

Comment: @kleopatra : Please see the SSCCE that i have posted.

Comment: sorry but that's completely wrong: you must make the _model_ fire the appropriate event in its implementation (vs. manually accessing its listeners) Suspect that the indices are off, not willing to dig, though as it is not a SSCCE (violating the stand-alone as it has dependencies on Departement/Employee). There are other errors as well (like f.i. returning a view in the model), so I suggest you re-read up on some basics first (the treeModel part is nothing special to JX or treeTable, just the same as plain core)

Comment: @kleopatra : "model fire the appropriate event in its implementation "..so u mean that the event should be fired in some method inside the TestModel class. That means the "this" parameter in the TreeModelEvent constructor has to be a model object..Otherwise this would have worked..correct?

Comment: @kleopatra : added the department and employee class

Comment: fine - now fix the other error and make the model behave. Repeating: look at the implementations of other TreeModels - f.i. Default/Tree/TableModel - to see what exactly to do in the firing. And use TreeModelSupport, it alliviates the pain considerably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, the reason boils down to an incorrect event (that you manually created in your action). Apart from the (minor) incorrect source, it's the path argument that's wrong: There are two constructors for a TreeEvent which you mixed up

```
// one taking a TreePath
public TreeModelEvent(Object source, TreePath path, int[] childIndices,
          Object[] children)

// the other taking an array of nodes to the root
public TreeModelEvent(Object source, Object[] path, int[] childIndices,
          Object[] children)

// mixture (**WRONG**)
TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, 
    // this is an array with the path as single element
    new Object[] {rootNew.getPathForRow(3)}, // harcoding because i know i am deleting from dept2
    new int[]{1}, //hardcoding as i am removing emp4
    new Object[] {emp4});

// technically correct (but **don't** - TreeModelSupport does it for you :-) 
TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, 
    // this is an array with the path as single element
    rootNew.getPathForRow(3), // harcoding because i know i am deleting from dept2
    new int[]{1}, //hardcoding as i am removing emp4
    new Object[] {emp4});
```

The real issue is the manual firing under the feet of the model: it's model's inherent responsibility to notify its listeners, so best provide it with api to remove an employee. Even then don't create the event manually which *can* be done incorrectly easily, that's why SwingX has TreeModelSupport to ease the pain.

```
// public api in your custom model
public void removeEmployee(Departement dept, Employee emp) {
    TreePath path = new TreePath(new Object[] {depList, dept});
    int index = dept.empList.indexOf(emp);
    dept.empList.remove(emp);
    modelSupport.fireChildRemoved(path, index, emp);
}

// its usage in application code
TestModel model = (TestModel) rootTree.getModel();
model.removeEmployee(dept2, emp4);
```

---

Unrelated to the notification issue, don't ever return *view* from *model* methods, the correct getValueAt would be something like

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(Object arg0, int arg1) {
    if (arg0 instanceof Employee) {

        Employee emp = (Employee) arg0;
        return emp.getName();
    } else if (arg0 instanceof Departement) {
        Departement dept = (Departement) arg0;
        return dept.getName();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: @mKorbel indeed - what did you want to say :-)

Comment: i ll say - "Thanks a  lot @kleopatra" U saved the day!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `reload()` method to your custom model using the `DefaultTreeTableModel` version as a guide. There's an example [here](http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Swing-Library/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/treetable/DefaultTreeTableModel.java.htm) that calls `fireTreeStructureChanged()`.